# UseSelector returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, redux

this peace of code sould watch the state of a cart containing a bunch of bets made by the user

`const { games } = useSelector((state: any) => state.cart)`
whitch i pass to another component like this

`<AppRecentUserGame games={games} filter={gameChoice} />`

at the homepage it should receive this games const and then render that bets list filter by type or not

```
interface AppRecentUserGameProps {
  games: Bet[];
  filter: GameTypes;
}

export const AppRecentUserGame = ({
  games,
  filter
}: AppRecentUserGameProps) => {
  const [filterGame, setFilterGame] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    setFilterGame(filter.type);
  }, [filter]);

  const filteredGames = () => {
    if (filterGame === "") {
      return !!games.length ? (
        games.map((game: any) => (
          <CartItem key={game.id} color={game.color}>
            <p>{formatNumberInArray(game.gameNumbers)}</p>
            <div>
              <p>
                {dateFormatValue(new Date(game.betDate))} - (
                {priceFormatted(game.price)})
              </p>
            </div>
            <strong>{game.type}</strong>
          </CartItem>
        ))
      ) : (
        <EmptyContainer>
          <EmptyCart />
        </EmptyContainer>
      );
    } else if (games && filter) {
      const filterGame = games.filter((game) => game.type === filter.type);
      return filterGame.map((game: any) => (
        <CartItem key={game.id} color={game.color}>
          <p>{formatNumberInArray(game.gameNumbers)}</p>
          <div>
            <p>
              {dateFormatValue(new Date(game.betDate))} - (
              {priceFormatted(game.price)})
            </p>
          </div>
          <strong>{game.type}</strong>
        </CartItem>
      ));
    }
  };

  return <>{filteredGames()}</>;
};
```

whenever a user save the bets he made, tha group os bets must populate the cartSlice, witch later all will use to show the user that list of bets he made in tha homepage
here is how i handle the save process

```
const [cartsGames, setCartGames] = useState<Bet[]>([])  
const saveGame = () => {
    try {
      if (totalPrice < 30) {
        const minPrice = gameType["min-cart-value"] 
        throw new Error(
          `Adicione pelo menos ${priceFormatted(minPrice)} em Apostas`)
      }
      cartsGames.forEach((game) => {
        dispatch(CartActions.addToCart(game)) 
        console.log(game)
      }) 
      setCartGames([]) 
      setMessageToUser({
        description: "Aposta Feita, Boa Sorte!",
        color: "var(--spinner)",
        active: true,
      }) 
      setRedirect(true) 
    } catch (error) {
      setMessageToUser({
        description: error.message,
        color: "var(--blue)",
        active: true,
      }) 
    }
  }
```

here is my store

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { cartSlice } from "./cartSlc";
import { userSlice } from "./userSlc";
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: userSlice.reducer,
    cart: cartSlice.reducer
  },
});
```

the userSlice:

```
import { SignedUpUserProps } from "../types/userSignup";

const initialState: SignedUpUserProps = {
  users: [
    {
      id: "1",
      name: "test",
      email: "test@gmail.com",
      password: "123456789",
      recentGames: [],
    },

  ],
  isLogged: false,
};

const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState,
  reducers: { // actions
    createUser(state, action) {
      const newUser = action.payload;
      state.users.push(newUser);
    },
    logIn(state) {
      state.isLogged = true;
    },
    logOut(state) {
      state.isLogged = false;
    },
    saveInRecentGames(state, action) {
      const users = [...state.users];
      const user = users.find((user) => user.id === action.payload.id);
      if (user) {
        const prevState: any = [...user.recentGames];
        user.recentGames.push(prevState, ...action.payload.games);
      }
    },
  },
});

const UserActions = userSlice.actions;
export { userSlice, UserActions };
```

the cart slice

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { Cart } from "../types/cart";


const initialState: Cart = {
 game: [],
 totalPrice: 0,
};

const cartSlice = createSlice({
 name: "cart",
 initialState,
 reducers: {
   addToCart(state, action) {
     const newBet = action.payload
     state.game.push(newBet)
     state.totalPrice = state.totalPrice + newBet.price
   },
 },
})
const CartActions = cartSlice.actions
export { cartSlice, CartActions }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You select your state *games* with an "s" but when I look at your slice it is named without the "s".

`const { games } = useSelector((state: any) => state.cart)`

`const initialState: Cart = { game: [], totalPrice: 0, };`

Comment: OMG!! i was so blind. thank you sou much ♥

Comment: Np :) Glad I could help